# traverse var after sorting List using Linq

Tags: linq, traversal, var

I have a list of objects of class info_gain. which looks like this: (using it like a structure):

```
class info_gain 
        {
            public string words;
            public double ig;
        };

List <info_gain> InfoGain = new List<info_gain>();
```

Now I wanted to sort those objects in this list in descending order of their attribute ig.
for which I used

```
var result = from element in InfoGain
                    orderby element.ig descending
                          select element;
```

Now how should I traverse each object in this var result in a for loop?

Note: I have never used Linq before so the sorting statement may be incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `foreach` instead of `for`:

```
foreach(var item in result)
{
    // use item here
}
```

Or if you really need to use `for`, you can call `ToArray` first, to get an array instead of `IEnumerable`:

```
var resultArray = result.ToArray();
for(int i = 0; i < resultArray.Length; i++)
{
    var item = resultArray[i];
    // use item here
}
```

But I would go with `foreach`.

***Update***

To traverse only `X` first items from collection use `Take` extension method:

```
foreach(var item in result.Take(5))
{
    // use item here
}
```

Comment: i want to traverse only the first few elements so foreach wont help

Comment: @user2793036 See my update. You can still do that with `foreach`.

Answer (score 3):

Use foreach loop to traverse results of LINQ query:

```
foreach(var info in result)
  // use info.words or info.ig
```

BTW you can use lambda syntax to make your query more compact:

```
var result = InfoGain.OrderByDescending(element => element.ig);
```

To get only first few elements use [Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) operator:

```
var result = InfoGain.OrderByDescending(element => element.ig).Take(5);
```

Also you always can put query results into new list and work with it as with any other list:

```
var gains = InfoGain.OrderByDescending(element => element.ig).ToList();
```

Comment: i want to traverse only the first few elements so foreach wont help

Answer (score 0):

```
var result =
    from element in InfoGain
    orderby element.ig descending
    select element;

foreach (var element in result)
{
    //stuff
}
```

Or, more concisely,

```
foreach (var element in InfoGain.OrderByDescending(element => element.ig))
{
    //stuff
}
```

However, the benefit of Linq is that you often don't need to explicitly iterate. What would you be doing in the loop body? It may be possible to eliminate the explicit iteration using Linq methods.